# Multiline-String to SingleLine-String in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have `TextField` with property `keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,` which allows me to put and enter/line break on the text. I'm trying to replace all linebreaks with `<br>` tag to use on web.

```
String myStr;    // initialized with onChanged(value) callback
myStr.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
print(myStr);
```

output remains same in multilines:

```
I/flutter ( 8312): a
I/flutter ( 8312): b
I/flutter ( 8312): c
I/flutter ( 8312): d
I/flutter ( 8312): e
I/flutter ( 8312): f
```

What I want is :

```
I/flutter ( 8312): a<br>b<br>c<br>d<br>e<br>f
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [replaceAll](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) documentation, it returns back the replaced string. You just need to set it back to your myStr:

```
myStr = myStr.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
```